# Need help in python (for and while loop)

Tags: loops, python-3.x, for-loop, while-loop

Q) At   one college,    the tuition for a   full-time   student is  $8,000  per semester.   It  has been    announced   that    the tuition will    increase    by  3   percent each    year    for the next    5   years.  Write   a program with a loop that displays the projected semester tuition amount for the next 5 years.

This is what i get

### Semesters --     Tuition Amount

```
 1
 2
 3
 4 
 5
                 8240.00
                 8480.00
                 8720.00
                 8960.00
                 9200.00
```

This is what i want

### Semesters --  Tuition Amount

```
1                 8240.00
2                 8480.00
3                 8720.00
4                 8960.00
5                 9200.00
```

I want tuition amount next to semesters

This is my code

```
    fees = 8000
    amount = 240
    MAX = 9200

print('Semester \t Tuition Amount')
print('----------------------------')

for x in range(1,6):
     print(x)

while fees<MAX:
     fees += amount
     print('\t\t',format(fees,'.2f'))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What exactly is your question? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details. Please [edit] these details into your post so that other users are able to help you. See also [ask], and be sure you have provided a [mcve]. Also, [please don't post console output as an image](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3933332), but instead copy/paste it and [use Markdown's code formatting](//$SITEURL$/help/formatting).

Comment: want i want is, that tuition amount need to be next to semester, and i dont know how to do that. I tried my best to fix but i cant, so i need help on it           if they look at my screenshot they will get the idea

Comment: Please read my comment again, as well as the four pages I linked to. Many users here (myself included) would be happy to help you, but you need to put in the effort to write a high-quality question.

Comment: Oops, I messed up on the last link. Here is the correct one: [Markdown code formatting help](//stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: is this enough information to understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're print the years and then the fees. Python's `print` automatically adds a line break after each `print` statement. So what you want is to output the year and tuition within the same `print` statement:

```
fees, amount = 8000, 240
print('Semester\tTuition Amount')
print('-----------------------------------------')
for x in range(1, 6):
     fees += amount
     print(x, format(fees, '.2f'), sep='\t\t')
```